# locale error with apt-get install

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, locale

Unable to install any new package or software using `apt-get install` on Ubuntu 14.04,
error details

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed. 
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings: 
    LANGUAGE = (unset), 
    LC_ALL = (unset), 
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1" 
    are supported and installed on your system. 
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). 
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed. 
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings: 
    LANGUAGE = (unset), 
    LC_ALL = (unset), 
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1" 
    are supported and installed on your system. 
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). 
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed. 
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings: 
    LANGUAGE = (unset), 
    LC_ALL = (unset), 
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1" 
    are supported and installed on your system. 
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). 
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory 
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory 
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5% 
(Reading database ... 10% 
(Reading database ... 15% 
(Reading database ... 20% 
(Reading database ... 25% 
(Reading database ... 30% 
(Reading database ... 35% 
(Reading database ... 40% 
(Reading database ... 45% 
(Reading database ... 50% 
(Reading database ... 55% 
(Reading database ... 60% 
(Reading database ... 65% 
(Reading database ... 70% 
(Reading database ... 75% 
(Reading database ... 80% 
(Reading database ... 85% 
(Reading database ... 90% 
(Reading database ... 95% 
(Reading database ... 100% 
(Reading database ... 337820 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack .../python-colorama_0.2.5-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb ... 
Unpacking python-colorama (0.2.5-0.1ubuntu2) ... 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-colorama_0.2.5-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack): 
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/colorama/ansi.py', which is also in package python-batteryonboardservices 0.1-1 
Preparing to unpack .../python-setuptools_3.3-1ubuntu2_all.deb ... 
Unpacking python-setuptools (3.3-1ubuntu2) ... 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-setuptools_3.3-1ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack): 
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py', which is also in package python-batteryonboardservices 0.1-1 
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-colorama_0.2.5-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb 
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-setuptools_3.3-1ubuntu2_all.deb 
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pip: 
 python-pip depends on python-colorama; however: 
  Package python-colorama is not installed. 
 python-pip depends on python-setuptools (>= 0.6c1); however: 
  Package python-setuptools is not installed. 

dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--configure): 
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix locales check your language support settings - English (India) should be installed. If not, install it. Then run:

```
sudo locale-gen en_IN.UTF-8
```

If that doesn't generate the locale, you can use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and choose `en_IN UTF-8` from the massive list to do the same thing

After generating the locale you want, check the output of `locale`. You want to see:

```
LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

If you don't see `en_IN.UTF-8` for everything, then do this:

```
sudo update-locale LANG="en_IN.UTF-8" LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
```

and check `locale` again. If the `LC` variables are still wrong, then do:

```
nano ~/.pam_environment
```

and edit so it looks like this:

```
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_IN.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE=a4
```

(leave the `papersize` alone - I'm not sure what it should be for you!)

Save, exit, type: `source ~/.pam_environment` and now your `locale` is fixed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43885/discussion-on-answer-by-zanna-locale-error-with-apt-get-install).

Comment: Problem solved.
I removed my own Packages then run these following commands:
'sudo apt-get clean'
'sudo apt-get autoremove'
'sudo apt-get update'
'sudo dpkg --configure -a'
'sudo apt-get install -f'
Thanks Zanna.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the Locale problem. Then it will work again.

To fix this problem, check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499794/how-can-i-fix-a-locale-warning-from-perl